# Using Response.TransmitFile throw PathTooLongException

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to transmit file to the client without buffering into memory
so I used Response.TransmitFile but this function throw PathTooLongException
I can handle this exception in IO.File Functions but I didnt find any soluton for this TransmitFile the stack trace  is like blew

```
Message :The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

StackTrace :   at System.IO.PathHelper.GetFullPathName()
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.TransmitFile(String filename, Int64 offset, Int64 length)
   at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in Download.aspx.cs:line 151
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read the error:

> Message :The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The
>   fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

It is really clear on what the problem is. I guess your path or file name is too long.

Check the filename you are transmitting at:

```
at System.Web.HttpResponse.TransmitFile(String filename, Int64 offset, Int64 length)
at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Inetpub\dl1.isdm.ir\Download.aspx.cs:line 151
```

Comment: My Friend I Know why that excpetion is thrown, the question is how to handle path longer than 260 character this is limit of .net not windows api and I dont have permission to rename file or folders so its needed to b handled

Comment: As far as i know it is the limit of the underling api .net uses.

Comment: no there is workarounds for this limitation in other functions in .net just google it  but I didnt find any for this function